# What's the fastest way to run T4MVC manually in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, t4mvc

I'm working on a fairly large project that uses T4MVC. Due to the project size, it takes quite a long time to run my T4MVC template, so using AutoT4MVC is too slow for my scenario.

So every time I change something vital aboutm my action methods, I have to select the T4MVC template, right-click, then click "run custom tool". It's quite tedious and I'm sure there's a better way.

Since AutoT4MVC is not an option, is there any plugin or hack that would allow me to place a button on my IDE that will run the T4MVC template included in my project?

Answer (score 3):

There is a menu item under Build -> Transform all T4 Templates. This will run all the templates in your solution. This command is also available on the Build toolbar, so if you turn that on (View -> Toolbars -> Build) you'll get the button you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to do basically what AutoT4MVC does, but based on some manual trigger. Or maybe you should suggest on https://github.com/bennor/AutoT4MVC to add a way to turn off automatic mode, and instead rely on a manual action.

I run T4MVC, but AutoT4MVC is a separate project that I'm less familiar with.